# Fast implementation of complementary error function with 5-digit accuracy

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point, floating-accuracy

[While this is a self-answered question, I will happily upvote and accept any alternative answer that either provides superior accuracy for the same amount of computational work or reduces the amount of computational work while maintaining the same level of accuracy.]

I have previously [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966695/vectorizable-implementation-of-complementary-error-function-erfcf) how to compute the complementary error function `erfcf()` with a maximum error of less than three ulps. This can serve as a building block for additional functions, such as the CDF of the standard normal distribution Φ(x) = ½ erfc (-√½ x) or the Gaussian Q-function, Q(x) = 1-Φ(x) = ½ erfc (√½ x). However, for some use cases computation fully accurate  to single precision is not needed while the contribution of `erfc()` evaluations to total run-time is not negligible.

The literature provides various low-accuracy approximations to the complementary error function, but they are either limited to a subset of the full input domain, or optimized for absolute error, or computationally too complex, for example by requiring multiple invocations of transcendental functions. How could one go about implementing `erfcf()` with high performance and with a relative accuracy of about 5 decimal digits *across the entire input domain*?

Comment: What is the purpose of this question and answer. If you want a feedback you need to post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gulpr: The purpose is to put information on record, furthering Stack Overflow’s goal of being a durable repository of programming questions and answers. [Stack Overflow encourages self-answered questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @njuffa, Are you trying to make a faster, yet perhaps less accurate, `erfc()` for `float` than the standard library `erfcf()` or re-inventing one from scratch as an exercise?  IOWs, why would one want to use this `fast_erfcf()` rather than `erfcf()` which is 70% faster and has 2.5x  better accuracy?

Comment: Reference: [wolfram erfc()](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `fast_erfcf()` is a classical trade off of speed for accuracy, for any platform. This is not an excercise in trying to beat the performance of the `erfcf()` implementation of the Intel compiler; that is just the compiler I used for my development work (as if offers clean IEEE-754 compliant FP handling). The literature is full of low-precision approximations for the complementary error function and new ones keep getting added; I wanted to grab one but all had one of the shortcomings noted in the question so I decided to make my own.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Example benchmark: Sum erfc function values for all `float`s between zero and `10.5f` in 1 ulp increments. Xeon W-2133, MSVC 19.27.29112, `cl /W4 /O2 /arch:AVX512 /favor:INTEL64 /fp:precise`. Using MSVC's built-in `erfcf()`: 44.5 seconds. Using `fast_erfcf()` with `USE_FMA=0`: 26.8 seconds. Using `fast_erfcf()` with `USE_FMA=1`: 20.5 seconds. This is just an example, and your use case may suggest other kinds of benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback to detail your goals.

Comment: @njuffa Idea: Rather than `exp(-x*x)`, consider a user function that does `power(2,-x*x)` crafted for this code. It has a singular advantage:  result may be realizable with lower error considering FP is binary based.  `exp(a)` has nasty relative error when `a` is large and it has error in it (which it does as `x*x` has error).

Comment: @chux - ReinstateMonica I looked into using `exp2(-x*x)` instead of `exp(-x*x)` early on, and found that the resulting functions is *more* difficult to approximate to the desired accuracy, requiring additional terms. Having implemented both `expf()` and `exp2f()` *in the same style*, their ulp-accuracy is practically the same. FWIW, *any* exponential-type function suffers from the problem of error magnification, and this can be addressed by computing x*x to higher accuracy, in particular pair-precision, which is easy to do when using FMA but still adds operations.

Comment: @njuffa Yes, my thought was more along the lines of `exp2f()` and sounds like you have delved into that too. Perhaps I will dig into that deeper too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could one go about implementing `erfcf()` with high performance and with a relative accuracy of about 5 decimal digits across the entire input domain?

This answer, like [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741403/2410359), does achieve *about* 5 decimal digits relative accuracy<sup>*1</sup>.  To achieve *at least* 5 likely obliges another term in the rational polynomial - which I doubt will slow the performance much.

**Special values**

In addition to performance and accuracy, the result of a `my_erfc(x)` for select values should be considered.

For `x` near 0.0, the result should be 1.0 exactly.  This follows [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Example: A user may readily rely on `my_cos(0.0) == 1.0`, or `my_exp(0.0) == 1.0`, so should `my_erfc(0.0) == 1.0`

Fortunately this is not hard to accomplish when a rational polynomial is used with coefficients of 1.0.  See below.

**Take advantage of the linear region**

About 45% of all `float` are such that the `erfc()` is a simple linear equation with high accuracy.

```
#define TWO_OVER_ROOT_PI 1.1283791670955125738961589031215f
#define ERFC_SMALL 0.0053854f

float fast_erfcf_alt(float x) {
  if (fabsf(x) < ERFC_SMALL) {
    return 1.0f - TWO_OVER_ROOT_PI * x;
  }
  ...
}
```

**Define performance rating**

One could rate code in a worst case, what is the slowest for all `float x`?

I suspect OP is more interested in an assessment from `x= 0.0` up to when `erfc(x)` is 0.0 (~`x == 10`) in a *linear* progression.

Sample performance results and test code follows.  Of course, hard to beat the C library's crafted code.

```
0 time: 0.594  erfcf (Library function)
1 time: 0.703  fast_erfcf (OP's answer)
2 time: 0.688  fast_erfcf_alt (This answer)
```

```
int main(void) {

  float (*f[3])(float) = {erfcf, fast_erfcf, fast_erfcf_alt };
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    clock_t c0, c1;

    c0 = clock();
    float dx = 10.0f - nextafterf(10, 0);
    for (float x = 10.0f; x >= 0.0f; x -= dx) {
      f[i](x);
    }
    c1 = clock();
    printf("%d time: %g\n", i, (double) (c1 - c0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  }
}
```

---

Following code is modeled after OP self answer and incorporates ideas mentioned above.

```
#define TWO_OVER_ROOT_PI 1.1283791670955125738961589031215f
#define ERFC_SMALL 0.0053854f

float fast_erfcf_alt(float x) {
  if (fabsf(x) < ERFC_SMALL) {
    return 1.0f - TWO_OVER_ROOT_PI * x;
  }

  float a, c, e, p, q, r, s;
  a = fabsf(x);
  c = fminf(a, 10.5f);
  s = -c * c;
#if USE_BUILTIN_EXP
  e = expf(s);
#else // USE_BUILTIN_EXP
    e = my_expf (s);
#endif // USE_BUILTIN_EXP
  q = 0.374177223624056f;
  p = -5.00032254520701E-05f;
  q = q * c + 1.29051354328887f;
  p = p * c + 0.212358010453875f;
  q = q * c + 1.84437448399707f;
  p = p * c + 0.715675302663111f;
  q = q * c + 1.0f;
  p = p * c + 1.0f;

  r = e / q;
  r = r * p;
  if (x < 0.0f)
    r = 2.0f - r;
  if (isnan(x))
    r = x + x;
  return r;
}
```

Note: I'd consider eliminating `c = fminf(a, 10.5f);`.

This code's error results using OP's answer test harness.
(`#define USE_FMA (0)` and `#define USE_BUILTIN_EXP (1))`.

It's relative error (1.20e-05) vs. OP's error (1.06e-05) is primarily due to using `1.0` in both polynomials `p` and `q`.

Other code could use OP's answer's `p` and `q` and this answer's `if (fabs(x) < ERFC_SMALL)` for a best of both.  Additional work needed to see how well the linear and rational polynomial sections meet.

```
 * This answer
 * max rel err = 1.203212e-05 @  9.19353199e+00
 * max abs err = 9.690295e-06 @ -7.19872937e-02
 * max ulp err = 1.877379e+02 @  8.03564072e+00
 *
 * OP's answer
 * max rel err = 1.061202e-05 @  4.35268253e-01
 * max abs err = 9.398669e-06 @ -9.19871107e-02
 * max ulp err = 1.755724e+02 @  2.46583080e+00
```

---

As an extra, below is a graphical view of OP's error over the [0... ~10] range.  I found it illuminating to show where errors develop.

[image: erfc error]

---

<sup>*1</sup> Low relative accuracy is not possible in the [sub-normal range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741402/fast-implementation-of-complementary-error-function-with-5-digit-accuracy/77794510#comment137059643_77742490) of answers.

Comment: I will look at the updated answer shortly. FWIW, triggered by your earlier comment about the lack of a smooth transition at zero (due to minimax approximations having error peaks at both ends, one end being at zero here), I had started to investigate what would happen to accuracy if I constrain the leading coefficients of both numerator and denominator to `1.0f`. Based on your accuracy data here, it seems your approach works somewhat better, which is interesting.

Comment: @njuffa, "if I constrain the leading coefficients of both numerator and denominator to 1.0f" --> might get a like result as this answer.

Comment: My attempts to generate rational approximations incorporating that constraint have all resulted in utter failure (probably due to misconceptions on my part how to go about it; this is not something I normally do). I have verified the stated error bounds for your set of coefficients on my local system, and am presently running the set through my heuristic tuner to see how close it can move the error bounds towards those provided in my answer.

Comment: @njuffa FWIW, your question has been fun and a learning experience for me.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. My approximation tuner with `USE_BUILTIN_EXP==1` converged to this:  `/* max rel err = 1.137295e-5 @ 8.01219559; max abs err = 9.512059e-6 @ -6.88479543e-2; max ulp err = 188.2552 @ 4.55690527 */ q = 3.74177814e-1f; p = -4.98741865e-5f; q = q * c + 1.29051733e+0f; p = p * c + 2.12357596e-1f; q = q * c + 1.84437072e+0f; p = p * c + 7.15674818e-1f; q = q * c + 1.0f; p = p * c + 1.0f;`

Comment: With `USE_BUILTIN_EXP==1` and `USE_FMA==1`, my approximation tuner converged to: `/* max rel err = 1.134736e-5 @ 8.00851154; max abs err = 9.441238e-6 @ -7.28745162e-2; max ulp err = 186.9355 @ 4.48175621 */ q = 3.74177963e-1f; p = -4.98741865e-5f; q = fmaf (q, c, 1.29051721e+0f); p = fmaf (p, c, 2.12357655e-1f);q = fmaf (q, c, 1.84436941e+0f); p = fmaf (p, c, 7.15674758e-1f); q = fmaf (q, c, 1.0f); p = fmaf (p, c, 1.0f);`

Comment: @njuffa Using your function, but with `double` as used by [Martin Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77808667/2410359)  with `exp()` and a new `q = 0.372032366435783f;   p = -5.17860698411427E-05f;   q = q * c + 1.28684034808953f;   p = p * c + 0.211180964525875f;   q = q * c + 1.8420670415641f;   p = p * c + 0.713380400611909f;   q = q * c + 1.0f;   p = p * c + 1.0f;` resulted in `max rel err = 9.915155e-06 @  7.69983605e-02 max abs err = 9.114271e-06 @ -7.18137547e-02
max ulp err = 1.584001e+02 @  2.33147717e+00` meting your goal.  On my machine it was 20% faster  than your original.

Answer (score 4):

The following assumes a platform that complies with the IEEE-754 (2008) floating-point standard, on which `float` is mapped to the IEEE-754 `binary32` format, and that uses the same endianness between 32-bit integers and `float`. It is further assumed that a C toolchain is available which (by setting appropriate command-line switches, if need be) preserves IEEE-754 semantics. I used the Intel C/C++ compiler with the switches `-march=skylake-avx152 -O3 -fp-model=precise`.

As the complementary error function is symmetric about (0,1), one can focus on function inputs in the positive half-plane. Here the function decays roughly like exp(-x<sup>2</sup>), and with `float` computation it underflows to zero for arguments x > 10.5. If one plots erfc(x) / exp(-x<sup>2</sup>) on [0, 10.5] the shape suggests that it is somewhat difficult to approximate with a polynomial, but should be easily approximated by a rational function, that is, the ratio of two polynomials. Some initial experiments showed that two polynomials each of degree 3 should be sufficient to achieve five-digit accuracy.

While there are many tools available that can generate polynomial approximations, this is unfortunately not the case with rational approximations. I used a modification of the Remez algorithm to generate an initial minimax approximation R(x) = P(x)/Q(x) to erfc(x) / exp(-x<sup>2</sup>), but had to follow-up with a fairly extensive heuristic search to arrive at an approximation that provides *close* to equi-oscillation of the error peaks and *almost* achieves a relative error of 10<sup>-5</sup>, with remaining differences being negligible for my needs.

By computing erfc(x) = exp(-x<sup>2</sup>) R(x) the accuracy achieved is obviously dependent on the accuracy of a platform's `expf()` implementation. In my experience, faithfully-rounded implementations of this function (with maximum error <= 1 ulp) are common. While the Intel compiler comes with a highly accurate math library that provides a nearly correctly-rounded implementation (maximum error very close to 0.5 ulps), I also tried my own faithfully-rounded alternative `my_expf()` with larger error and observed only a very minor impact on accuracy of `fast_erfcf()`.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define USE_FMA          (1)
#define USE_BUILTIN_EXP  (0)

#if !USE_BUILTIN_EXP
float my_expf (float a);
#endif // USE_BUILTIN_EXP

/* Fast computation of the complementary error function. For argument x > 0
   erfc(x) = exp(-x*x) * P(x) / Q(x), where P(x) and Q(x) are polynomials. 
   If expf() is faithfully rounded, the following error bounds should hold:
   Maximum relative error < 1.065e-5, maximum absolute error < 9.50e-6, and 
   maximum ulp error < 176.5
*/
float fast_erfcf (float x)
{
    float a, c, e, p, q, r, s;
    a = fabsf (x);
    c = fminf (a, 10.5f);
    s = -c * c;
#if USE_BUILTIN_EXP
    e = expf (s);
#else // USE_BUILTIN_EXP
    e = my_expf (s);
#endif // USE_BUILTIN_EXP
#if USE_FMA
    q =             3.82346243e-1f;  //  0x1.8785c6p-2
    p =            -4.38094139e-5f;  // -0x1.6f8000p-15
    q = fmaf (q, c, 1.30382288e+0f); //  0x1.4dc756p+0
    p = fmaf (p, c, 2.16852024e-1f); //  0x1.bc1ceap-3
    q = fmaf (q, c, 1.85278833e+0f); //  0x1.da5056p+0
    p = fmaf (p, c, 7.23953605e-1f); //  0x1.72aa0cp-1
    q = fmaf (q, c, 9.99991655e-1f); //  0x1.fffee8p-1
    p = fmaf (p, c, 1.00000000e+0f); //  0x1.000000p+0
#else // USE_FMA
    q =         3.82346272e-1f; //  0x1.8785c8p-2f
    p =        -4.38243151e-5f; // -0x1.6fa000p-15
    q = q * c + 1.30382371e+0f; //  0x1.4dc764p+0
    p = p * c + 2.16852218e-1f; //  0x1.bc1d04p-3
    q = q * c + 1.85278797e+0f; //  0x1.da5050p+0
    p = p * c + 7.23953605e-1f; //  0x1.72aa0cp-1
    q = q * c + 9.99991596e-1f; //  0x1.fffee6p-1
    p = p * c + 1.00000000e+0f; //  0x1.000000p+0
#endif // USE_FMA
    r = e / q;
    r = r * p;
    if (x < 0.0f) r = 2.0f - r;
    if (isnan(x)) r = x + x;
    return r;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

/* Exponential function. Maximum error 0.86565 ulps */
float my_expf (float a)
{
    float f, r, j, s, t;
    int i;
    unsigned int ia;

    // exp(a) = 2**i * exp(f); i = rintf (a / log(2))
    j = fmaf (1.442695f, a, 12582912.f); // 0x1.715476p0 // log2(e)
    j = j - 12582912.f; // 0x1.8p23 // 2**23+2**22
    f = fmaf (j, -6.93145752e-1f, a); // -0x1.62e400p-1  // log_2_hi 
    f = fmaf (j, -1.42860677e-6f, f); // -0x1.7f7d1cp-20 // log_2_lo 
    i = (int)j;
    // approximate r = exp(f) on interval [-log(2)/2, +log(2)/2]
    r =             1.37805939e-3f;  // 0x1.694000p-10
    r = fmaf (r, f, 8.37312452e-3f); // 0x1.125edcp-7
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.16695364e-2f); // 0x1.555b5ap-5
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.66664720e-1f); // 0x1.555450p-3
    r = fmaf (r, f, 4.99999851e-1f); // 0x1.fffff6p-2
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.00000000e+0f); // 0x1.000000p+0
    r = fmaf (r, f, 1.00000000e+0f); // 0x1.000000p+0
    // exp(a) = 2**i * r
    ia = (i > 0) ? 0 : 0x83000000;
    s = uint32_as_float (0x7f000000 + ia);
    t = uint32_as_float ((i << 23) - ia);
    r = r * s;
    r = r * t;
    // handle special cases: severe overflow / underflow
    if (fabsf (a) >= 104.0f) r = (a < 0) ? 0.0f : INFINITY;
    return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint64_t double_as_uint64 (double a)
{
    uint64_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

double floatUlpErr (float res, double ref)
{
    uint64_t refi, i, j, err;
    int expoRef;
    
    /* ulp error cannot be computed if either operand is NaN, infinity, zero */
    if (isnan (res) || isnan (ref) || isinf(res) || isinf (ref) ||
        (res == 0.0f) || (ref == 0.0)) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    i = ((int64_t)float_as_uint32 (res)) << 32;
    expoRef = (int)(((double_as_uint64 (ref) >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023);
    refi = double_as_uint64 (ref);
    if (expoRef >= 129) {
        j = (refi & 0x8000000000000000ULL) | 0x7fffffffffffffffULL;
    } else if (expoRef < -126) {
        j = ((refi << 11) | 0x8000000000000000ULL) >> 8;
        j = j >> (-(expoRef + 126));
        j = j | (refi & 0x8000000000000000ULL);
    } else {
        j = ((refi << 11) & 0x7fffffffffffffffULL) >> 8;
        j = j | ((uint64_t)(expoRef + 127) << 55);
        j = j | (refi & 0x8000000000000000ULL);
    }
    err = (i < j) ? (j - i) : (i - j);
    return err / 4294967296.0;
}

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t argi, resi, refi, diff;
    float arg, res, reff, abserrloc = NAN, relerrloc = NAN, ulperrloc = NAN;
    double ref, relerr, abserr, ulperr;
    double maxabserr = 0, maxrelerr = 0, maxulperr = 0;

    argi = 0;
    do {
        arg = uint32_as_float (argi);
        ref = erfc ((double)arg);
        res = fast_erfcf (arg);
        reff = (float)ref;
        resi = float_as_uint32 (res);
        refi = float_as_uint32 (reff);
        ulperr = floatUlpErr (res, ref);
        if (ulperr > maxulperr) {
            ulperrloc = arg;
            maxulperr = ulperr;
        }
        abserr = fabs (res - ref);
        if (abserr > maxabserr) {
            abserrloc = arg;
            maxabserr = abserr;
        }
        if (fabs (ref) >= 0x1.0p-126) {
            relerr = fabs ((res - ref) / ref);
            if (relerr > maxrelerr) {
                relerrloc = arg;
                maxrelerr = relerr;
            }
        }
        diff = (resi > refi) ? (resi - refi) : (refi - resi);
        if (diff > 200) {
            printf ("diff=%u @ %15.8e : res=% 15.8e  ref=% 15.8e\n", 
                    diff, arg, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        argi++;
    } while (argi);

    printf ("max rel err = %.6e @ % 15.8e\n"
            "max abs err = %.6e @ % 15.8e\n"
            "max ulp err = %.6e @ % 15.8e\n",
            maxrelerr, relerrloc, 
            maxabserr, abserrloc,
            maxulperr, ulperrloc);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please append the output you saw. (Approximate run time useful too.)

Comment: I saw `max rel err = 1.060158e-05 @  1.12632227e+00
max abs err = 9.462895e-06 @ -9.60391834e-02
max ulp err = 1.761760e+02 @  1.08563566e+00` at about 10 minutes.

Comment: `if (isnan(x)) r = x + x;` deserves a comment.  What is the goal of this line?  `if (isnan(x)) return x;` in the function top seems like a better alternative.

Comment: If you're going to rely on `exp`, processing the domain side looks like an easier fit: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+log%28erfc%28x%29%29+from+0+to+10

Comment: @MattTimmermans I tried the exp(R(x)) approach and only achieved a *higher* error bound, which I explained as being caused by error magnification inherent in exponential functions. This approach also reduces the inherent parallelism in the code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am not sure why NaN-handling would require a special comment. Special cases like NaN should be rare and don't have to be handled fast. In terms of making the common path fast, it is often better to handle them at the end as a conditional overwrite, so that is the pattern I have mostly been using the past 20 years. The `x+x` is a *common idiom* that triggers an exception when an SNAN is encountered with FP exceptions unmasked, and forces SNAN to QNAN conversion when FP exceptions are masked, which is IEEE-754 compliant.

Comment: @njuffa "The `x+x` is a _common idiom_ that triggers ..." --> interesting.   I would not say it is that common and hence the benefit of a comment concerning triggering.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Take a look at FDLIBM, for example. This math library from the 1990s (AFAIK, largely the work of K. C. Ng at Sun) serves as the basis of other math libraries to this day.

Comment: Why 10.5?  Note that `erfc(10.05)` (extra 0 intended here) returns a value less than half of `FLT_TRUE_MIN`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Correct, 10.06 or thereabouts is the cutoff for round-off to zero for `float`. Various processor architectures provide for the incorporation of floating-point literal constants into the instruction encoding, *but only with low precision*. The choice of 10.5 instead of 10.06 increases the likelihood of meeting this low-precision requirement and does not hurt anything I can think of.

Comment: Thanks - naked magic numbers deserve some dressing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I felt I already invested enough time in this Q/A beyond my immediate needs. If I offer a solution based on FMA alone, some people don't like it so I added a variant tweaked for no-FMA. If I rely on the super-accurate Intel math library, some people find fault with that, so I added `my_expf()` as another point of reference for reproducability. If I don't show my ulp computation, some people clamor to see it so I threw in a complete test framework. I am happy to share what I already have, but I do want to limit the amount of work added just for SO.

Comment: OK, Happy New Year.

Comment: One possible idea that might improve the accuracy further or simplify the rational model needed is to precondition the approximation as erfc(x)*(0.575+x)/exp(-x^2) which then leaves only a very softly varying function for the rational polynomial to model. Constant chosen by eye from graph at double precision (about 0.6 for float).

Comment: @Martin Brown Thanks for the pointer. I used "linearization" for the full precision `erfcf()` I linked in the question, but had not gotten around to trying it here. I am really struggling with generating good rational approximations (still working on it), it would be good to get to something that can easily be approximated by a polynomial.

Comment: @njuffa I have now got working versions of precise polynomial and rational approximations using the julia based ARMremez code for P(x), P(x^2) and xP(x^2). You are welcome to give it a try. I'm typically getting ~40 good decimal digits out of 75.  BTW I see no alternative to FMA code for these optimised functions - nothing else preserves the accuracy well enough.

Comment: @Martin Brown Requiring FMA is fine. Most processor architectures these days support it. Not sure what you mean by "40 good decimal digits out of 75"? I am looking for something as fast as possible with **5-digit** accuracy, using `float` computation. My answer includes a test harness that you could use to evaluate your implementation before posting your answer.

Comment: @njuffa the remez solver is working internally with 75 decimal digit BigFloats and the solutions for coefficients that it finds are good to 40-45 decimal digits. Technically it hasn't always met the arbitrary convergence criterion that ARM uses but that looked wrong to me (so I relaxed it a little). If I can find a high precision erfc function in SpecialFunctions.jl I'll give it a whirl. I realise optimum rounding is critical.

Comment: @njuffa I'd like to re-use your sample answer to ask a question about a possible bug I have found in the Intel 2023 compiler code generator when /AVX2 and /fp:fast are selected along with the usual gofaster options the abserr value gets corrupted to Nan. Also some guidance to normal practice here - if you are agreeable should I repost all of the code or just the (simple) mods needed to demonstrate the fault quickly (and a pointer to here)? I'd like to have more eyes take a look at it before filing a bug report.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for your advice. I think this one is definitely a bug. I'll likely post it tomorrow. It turns out the the compliment of the loop increment counter ends up in maxabserr for a handful of unlucky values. The code transformations are pretty wild. This happens even when maxulperr is at the same location and correctly computed.

Comment: @njuffa icx - although this is the first time it has given me serious trouble. I'm working on an MRE for it whilst trying to preserve the bug. Usually I find Intel much faster code than any of the alternatives and throughput is my main goal.

Answer (score 1):

OP has provided a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741402/fast-implementation-of-complementary-error-function-with-5-digit-accuracy?noredirect=1#comment137058196_77741402) with the range used to assess performance testing: 0.0 to 10.5 in 1 ULP steps.

As about 40% of all `float` [-1.6e-08 ... +1.6e-08] return a value of about 1.0, code could use the following.  For me, the overall performance at least *doubled*.

```
float fast_erfcf(float x) {
  if (fabsf(x) <= 1.60e-8) {  // or maybe a bit more.
    return 1.0;
  }
  ...
}
```

Since such a large range of `float` in `erfc(x)` can return 1.0, I recommend this up front test.

Advantages include:

- Much faster for for 40% of all `float`.
- `erfc(x_near_0)` are expected to return 1.0.  OP's `fast_erfcf(0.0)` returns 1.00000834.  Acceptable, given the large ULP being tolerated.  Still 1.0 is nice.
- OP's `fast_erfcf(small negative value)` returns 0.999991536.  Acceptable, given the large ULP being tolerated, yet it is desirable to have `erfc(x) >= erfc(next x towards + infinity)` when possible.

Also: Suggest performance testing for the most interesting values is conducted in the [0.1 .... 10.0] range.

---

This suggestion did not help OP much, so moving it to the bottom of this answer.

Instead of performing *e*<sup>x</sup> with [`my_expf(float a)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741403/2410359) consider *2*<sup>x</sup> with say `my_exp2f(float a)`.  (This will impact the constants of the rational function.)

Effectively `j = fmaf(1.442695f, a, 12582912.f);` is removed.

Performing exponentiation is slightly easier with base 2 than base *e*.

I estimate a few percent faster code (~3%), and not much change in ULP results.

True, a micro-optimization, but it is effectively free as it does not add any real complexity to the link answer's approach.

Comment: As explained in the description, `my_expf()` was just used to demonstrate that it does not matter much whether `expf()` is nearly correctly rounded or more generally faithfully rounded. For what it is worth, `expf()` vs `exp2f()` is often a wash in terms of performance, and on some platforms `expf()` is more highly optimized.

Comment: True about possibilities of `expf()` vs `exp2f()`, yet certainly your `my_expf()` vs `my_exp2f()` can have the slightly faster `my_exp2f()` as it needs 1 less line of code without code increases elsewhere, thus "reduces the amount of computational work while maintaining the same level of accuracy".

Comment: If we were to use `exp2f()` instead of `expf()` we need a different rational approximation R(x) and find that the function erfc(x)/exp2(x) that needs to be approximated is *harder* to approximate requiring higher degree polynomials, so overall it is a loss performance-wise. At least this is what I found when I tried it.

Comment: @njuffa Hmm, that was not expected.  IAC, you already have a set up to assess things and I am building one up.  It will take some time to validate.

Comment: @njuffa Another TBD idea: `my_expf ()` may be too good and overall `my_erfcf()` may tolerate less terms in `my_expf ()`.

Comment: As I said, I do **not** want to use `my_expf()` here, nor should anybody else. The goal is to use a platform's built-in `expf()` implementation. Even rudimentary or early-development platforms that don't offer the full C99 math library usually offer `expf()` (which along with log, sin, cos, atan is among the first functions built). `my_expf()` was used solely as a second reference point *for accuracy* as an example of an environment where  `expf()` is *not* nearly correctly rounded as with Intel's library.

Comment: Please note that the performance test I showed in a comment above was a purely *artificial* test case created in response to your question why one may want to use `fast_erfcf()` over `erfcf()`. Your suggestion to measure performance on [0.1, 10] is probably more realistic. The reason I specified relative accuracy is because I wanted/needed the tails. I also wanted to avoid branches so as not to interfere with future SIMD-ization.

Comment: "specified relative accuracy is because I wanted/needed the tails"--> _relative accuracy_ is very challenging when the result is in the smallest value portion of sub-normal numbers.  E.g. when the answer is `FLT_TRUE_MIN`, the relative error approaches 1.0.  I recommend to instead use ULP error to rate the quality of the function.   To summarize: it seems your goal is the fastest, not too complex code, that achieves a max ULP error of about  < 170 (maybe up to 256) over the `float` range that has minimal branching.

Comment: I completely agree that relative accuracy is meaningless for subnormals, for the reason you state. This is why my test framework, as posted, does **not** record relative accuracy for those cases, and also uses ulp error as a backup. It boils down to a question of presenting the issue, and this is the best way I managed of presenting it, considering that not everybody reading the [C] tag is aware of floating-point details you and I are aware of.

Comment: @njuffa Working on a more precise without increasing time solution.

Comment: @njuffa "more precise" did not pan out.  See new answer for a "about as precise" and faster.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that erfc(x) put up more of a fight than I was expecting but I now finally have a solution that is faster, only slightly more complex and 2x more accurate. It is faster although that advantage may be lost if @njuffa switches to double precision arithmetic internally. I'll start another thread about speed since there are some curiosities about FMA code timings that I really don't understand.

Tests were done in the OP's test harness with a minor modification to time each run.

To obtain a solution I had to modify my version of the ARM remez code and use a custom weighting to get the errors right down at the high end of the range. Incidentally reducing the range slightly to 10.0 (or looking at @chux graph) perhaps as low as 9.5 will give full 5 figure relative error accuracy.

The function I modelled as a rational P(x)/Q(x) was

```
 (erfc(x)/exp(-x^2)-1)/x   (excluding x==0)
```

The formal solution obtained by ARMremez code (modified) is:

```
 iter = 6 maxerr = 3.28148019434200456568158011254156762066636830e-06 
 (1.0+x*(0.8991604049044439664180350803894074305+ 
 x*(0.2900325421849880048302980017673262815200+
 x*(-6.0399785602952803731803658009133843823e-06))))
 /(-0.886123058281072972284447446285224409290+
 x*(-1.58327531146239316863922987677501888438287+
 x*(-1.065217231856749807713459915046806520098096+
 x*(-0.28983820234089701058660284313744428693980))))
```

Coefficients computed to 80 digits and truncated to indicated accuracy.

This is the code that resulted with coefficients retained to double precision digits but truncated to floating point by the compiler. I haven't been able to obtain a working pure float implementation (although it may be possible). There may be no point since doubles are faster!

The accuracy isn't quite what the Remez algorithm predicts but I have spent no time trying to look for a better coefficient set. The resulting C function is:

```
float d_fast_erfcf(float x)  
   // computation entirely in double precision to rule out rounding glitches
   // coefficients declared as floats (remove trailing f to get doubles)
{
   double a, e, r, s, c, p, q;
   a = fabs(x);
   c = fmin(a, 10.5);
   s = -c * c;
   e = exp(s);

   p = 1.0f + c * (0.89916040490444396641803508f + c * (0.29003254218498800483029800f + c * (-6.039978560295280373180365800e-06f)));
   q = -0.88612305828107297228444744628522f + c * (-1.5832753114623931686392298767750f + c * (-1.0652172318567498077134599150f + c * (-0.2898382023408970105866028431f)));
   r = e * (1+ c * p / q);

   if (x < 0.0) r = 2.0 - r;
   if (isnan(x)) r = x + x;
   return (float) r;
}

// Results uing MS V C/C++ 2022
// Pure float implementation is no good
// diff count 0   time taken 168.5
//
// max rel err = 1.28762e-05 @       9.12920189   0x1.24226cp+3
// max abs err = 3.60758e-06 @    -0.0615047403  -0x1.f7d8cap-5
// max ulp err = 200 @       8.77462292   0x1.18c9b6p+3
//
// float coefficients with double arithmetic is best buy
// diff count 0   time taken 108.1
// max rel err = 5.56595e-06 @       6.25805283   0x1.9083f0p+2
// max abs err = 3.543e-06 @    -0.0637716576  -0x1.05356ep-4
// max ulp err = 128 @      0.813420653   0x1.a078acp-1
//
// pure double coefficients and double arithmetic
// diff count 0   time taken 108.4
//
// max rel err = 5.5498e-06 @       9.15682793   0x1.2504bcp+3
// max abs err = 3.54332e-06 @    -0.0638476089  -0x1.058512p-4
// max ulp err = 128 @      0.813420653   0x1.a078acp-1
//
// OP original version
// diff count 0   time taken 195.34
//
// max rel err = 1.06016e-05 @       1.12632227   0x1.2056a8p+0
// max abs err = 9.4629e-06 @    -0.0960391834  -0x1.896062p-4
// max ulp err = 192 @   8.45171871e-06  0x1.1b97b6p-17
//
// Full disclosure quick test on Intel C++ 2023 full doubles
// diff count 0   time taken 252.868
// max rel err = 5.5498e-06 @       9.15682793   0x1.2504bcp+3
// max abs err = nan @    -0.0638476089  -0x1.058512p-4
// max ulp err = 128 @      0.813420653   0x1.a078acp-1
//
// I don't like the look of max abs error = nan !
```

The other quirk is that Intel uses concise FMA instructions whereas Microsoft uses separate multiply and add. The latter apparently runs quicker here!

I hope this provides you with a new set of coefficients to play with. I'd be interested to know what your rational Remex optimiser gets for that function.

Comment: At first look the improved accuracy derives from effectively adding one more term to the approximation, at the additional cost of one 1M + 1A?

Comment: For a pure `float` implementation using FMAs, my tuner converged to: `/* max rel err = 9.323338e-6 @ 6.42245102; max abs err = 3.633895e-6 @ -6.50273114e-2; max ulp err = 152.7799 @ 6.42245102 */ p = -6.03997978e-6f; p = fmaf (p, c, 2.90032744e-1f); p = fmaf (p, c, 8.99160624e-1f); p = fmaf (p, c, 1.0f); q = -2.89838761e-1f; q = fmaf (q, c, -1.06521523e+0f); q = fmaf (q, c, -1.58327532e+0f); q = fmaf (q, c, -8.86123061e-1f); r = fmaf (p / q, c, 1.0f) * e;` As one would expect, increasing the degree of the approximation by one improves the accuracy.

Comment: Pretty much. Anything fancier that I tried works well for modest x but goes haywire when you extend the range beyond x~5 (or vice versa). This series looked promising and fairly convergent but I can't tame it with my Remez code at present. (Maxima): (%i14) taylor((erfc(x)-1)*sqrt(%pi)/2+(exp(-x^2)-1+x^2)/2/x, x, 0, 16);
(%o14)/T/ -x+(7*x^3)/12-(11*x^5)/60+(5*x^7)/112-(19*x^9)/2160+(23*x^11)/15840-(3*x^13)/14560+(31*x^15)/1209600-...  BTW how do you tweak the coefficients that Remez spits out? I'm using simulated annealing but it takes too long! I'd love to have an LLL/PLSQ code for this step!

Comment: For a pure `float` implementation *without* FMAs, my tuner returned: `/* max rel err = 9.721465e-6 @ 6.52076149; max abs err = 3.647192e-6 @ -6.27824590e-2; max ulp err = 156.4300 @  3.65526581 */ p = -6.03997751e-6f; p = p * c + 2.90031374e-1f; p = p * c + 8.99160922e-1f; p = p * c + 1.0f; q = -2.89837450e-1f; q = q * c - 1.06521440e+0f; q = q * c - 1.58327568e+0f; q = q * c - 8.86122882e-1f; r = ((p / q) * c + 1) * e;` Increasing the degree of the approximation adds FP operations and lengthens the dependency chain; something I do *not* desire. May be useful to others, so (+1).

Comment: I am also using simulated annealing in my tuner. The trick is finding the "best" cooling rates and re-heating strategy. My heuristics often work well, but when creating approximations for answers to other questions I have at times had the same issue you seem to have here: While my simulated annealing delivered "meh!" results, other people's simulated annealing provided *great* results.So a bit of a black art, I am afraid.

Comment: One thing that makes erfc(x) very tricky is that the denominator is pretty badly behaved when x > 3 the terms using Horner are summed largest first. That coefficient series is diverging! Requiring such a large range of convergence stresses out the initial least squares guess beyond failure point. It is very frustrating that my odd function optimised code (made for tan(x)) won't touch this function at all!

Comment: It is precisely because `erfc()` is so difficult to handle with *simple* approximations (and after finding nothing suitable in the literature) that I posted my self-answered question. A more complex approach using "linearization" is demonstrated in the earlier answer I linked in my question here and leads to a core approximation that is much easier to generate. But the complexity drags down performance.

Comment: One final trick you might like to consider since you have your own private exp(x) approximation as well as the erfc(x) approximation is to face one off against the other (probably weighting exp(x) to be optimal for large x and erfc(x) for x < 3). Since you can control both of your approximations independently you don't have to use system true exp(x) you can use your own nearly exp that is asymptotically more like  erfc(x) when x is large.

Comment: @MartinBrown In terms of _speed_, using `p = 1.0f + c * (0.899...f + c * (0.2900...f + c *  ...` and `q = -0.8861...f + c * (-1.583...f + ...` code instead of OP's `q = 0.374...f;   p = -5.0003...E-05f; q = q * c + 1.290...7f;   p = p * c + 0.212...f; ...` re-organizes the order of operations.  This may favor timing one way or the other per implementation and not reflect a change in raw algorithm.  To better compare performance, consider using OP's `p = ...;, q = ...; p = ...;, q = ... ...` and report the timing.

Comment: @MartinBrown The [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77794510/2410359) green line shows increasing wobble @ `x` = 2.0, 4.0, 8.0 (and sqrt(32)).  These are due to the intermediate `float` terms exhibiting their limited precision and eventually negatively affecting the _max rel err_ we are trying to minimize.  If we use `double`, in other answers like here, we can use other optimized `p[],q[]` coefficients _without changing the algorithm_ to achieve  improved _max rel err_.

Comment: @MartinBrown ... IOWs, I'm suggesting the major improvements of this answer are due to intermediates with `double` vs `float` math and not so much because of the new `(erfc(x)/exp(-x^2)-1)/x` approach.  Still the new algorithm deserves consideration.

Comment: @chux I checked that. The removal of the first term makes quite a difference to the number of entries in the ULP==0 bin (roughly doubling them cf OP's algorithm). This is with pure float coefficients but doubles for c,p,q. Changing OP's algorithm to use doubles in the same positions merely gets it closer to the theoretical limit for that coefficient set with high precision arithmetic.  Using double coefficients really slows it down. BTW MSC code generation for all versions beats the Intel compiler for speed (even though the Intel code looks better and uses FMA).

Comment: @njuffa - I noticed Hart (p.140) does have some relative error erfc expressions for the same functional form on 0-4, 0-8 and 8-100 as ERFC5680-5725. That's the good news. The bad news is that I can't make any of them work and even the simplest ones bear no relation to the right answers from my optimiser (or least squares). Curiously the precision estimates are about right but the coefficients seem to be nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but rather interesting. I'm slowly getting to grips with GCC under Linux and finally got around to compiling your test harness and my various attempts together with system erfc() and erfcf() as references:

```
GCC -mavx2 -march=native -O2
```

There is a **big** surprise! GCC system library erfcf() is the fastest implementation of all. An order of magnitude more accurate too and 25% faster than the custom code! It is about 10% faster still with -ffast-math

I wonder how they have done that?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't find it on a first try but then I got this [link to Sun's version in erff.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/WebAssembly/musl/+/master/src/math/erff.c). That doesn't look to me like it should be faster but looks can be deceptive. There is a second oddity which I will post about in a related thread. One form of my algorithm is almost as fast but only on the MS C compiler. Intel code generation looks good and is more accurate FMA but slowest of the lot! My own attempt at SIMD FMA vectorisation of erfcf/exp in parallel failed miserably :(