# Nan problem with Intel 2022 compiler using AVX2 & /fp:fast

Tags: c, floating-point, nan, avx2, icx

I was playing with a test harness described in another post by @njaffa to try and make a faster more accurate erfc() function when I hit a peculiar bug that I am still unable to understand fully and would like some help with. I think the code is perfectly well behaved whilst pushing at some boundaries.

A purist might object to overflowing the counter argi for loop termination but that is not the issue. When compiled with the usual go faster options and specifically /fp:fast the code generated is wrong. I have added a few diagnostics that don't affect the problem and count the number of nans detected (but give inconsistent results).

NB It only fails on the Intel compiler and it must be set to /fp:fast and release (all other options work correctly as do all the other compilers that I have tried). FP strict and precise both work correctly on Intel.

I have simplified his code as much as possible whilst still retaining the errant behaviour I see here and it is reproduced below in its failing state:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// njuffa's fast erfc(x) and test harness (stripped down as far as I can) see 
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741402/fast-implementation-of-complementary-error-function-with-5-digit-accuracy/

// It only fails on the latest Intel 2022 compiler when /fp:fast and /O2 /Ob2 /Ot

/* Fast computation of the complementary error function. For argument x > 0
erfc(x) = exp(-x*x) * P(x) / Q(x), where P(x) and Q(x) are polynomials. 
If expf() is faithfully rounded, the following error bounds should hold:
Maximum relative error < 1.065e-5, maximum absolute error < 9.50e-6, and 
maximum ulp error < 176.5
*/
float fast_erfcf (float x)
{
  float a, c, e, p, q, r, s;
  a = fabsf (x);
  c = fminf (a, 10.5f);
  s = -c * c;
  e = expf (s);
  q =         3.82346272e-1f; //  0x1.8785c8p-2f
  p =        -4.38243151e-5f; // -0x1.6fa000p-15
  q = q * c + 1.30382371e+0f; //  0x1.4dc764p+0
  p = p * c + 2.16852218e-1f; //  0x1.bc1d04p-3
  q = q * c + 1.85278797e+0f; //  0x1.da5050p+0
  p = p * c + 7.23953605e-1f; //  0x1.72aa0cp-1
  q = q * c + 9.99991596e-1f; //  0x1.fffee6p-1
  p = p * c + 1.00000000e+0f; //  0x1.000000p+0
  r = e / q;
  r = r * p;
  if (x < 0.0f) r = 2.0f - r;
  if (isnan(x)) r = x + x;
  return r;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
  float r;
  memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
  return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
  uint32_t r;
  memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
  return r;
}

uint64_t double_as_uint64 (double a)
{
  uint64_t r;
  memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
  return r;
}

double floatUlpErr (float res, double ref)
{
  uint64_t refi, i, j, err;
  int expoRef;

  /* ulp error cannot be computed if either operand is NaN, infinity, zero */
  if (isnan (res) || isnan (ref) || isinf(res) || isinf (ref) ||
     (res == 0.0f) || (ref == 0.0)) {
    return 0.0;
  }
  i = ((int64_t)float_as_uint32 (res)) << 32;
  expoRef = (int)(((double_as_uint64 (ref) >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023);
  refi = double_as_uint64 (ref);
  if (expoRef >= 129) {
      j = (refi & 0x8000000000000000ULL) | 0x7fffffffffffffffULL;
  } else if (expoRef < -126) {
      j = ((refi << 11) | 0x8000000000000000ULL) >> 8;
      j = j >> (-(expoRef + 126));
      j = j | (refi & 0x8000000000000000ULL);
  } else {
      j = ((refi << 11) & 0x7fffffffffffffffULL) >> 8;
      j = j | ((uint64_t)(expoRef + 127) << 55);
      j = j | (refi & 0x8000000000000000ULL);
  }
  err = (i < j) ? (j - i) : (i - j);
  return err / 4294967296.0;
}

int main (void)
{
  uint32_t argi, last_argi;
  float arg, res, reff, abserrloc = NAN, ulperrloc = NAN;
  double ref, abserr, ulperr;
  double maxabserr = -0x1.2468Ap-127, maxulperr = -0x1.13579p-127; // tagged to spot in MMXreg
  unsigned int nancount = 0, loopcount = 0;

  //    argi = 0; // original code to test entire range - uses XMM8h,XMM10h & fails
  argi = float_as_uint32(-4.0); // this is a convenient hard failing value aka 0xc0800000 - uses XMM10h, XMM13h & fails
  //    argi = 0xff810000-0x007f0000; // this is the closest start value I found that fails with increment 0x007f0000

  do {
     if (argi == 0xff810000)
        printf("This time it will fail\n");
     arg = uint32_as_float (argi);
     ref = erfc ((double)arg);
     res = fast_erfcf (arg);
     ulperr = floatUlpErr (res, ref);
     if (ulperr > maxulperr) {
         ulperrloc = arg;
         maxulperr = ulperr;
     }
     abserr = fabs (res - ref);
     if (isnan(abserr)) {
        nancount++; // testing for nan here the bug persists
        printf("NaN @ %8x  ", argi); // this line will trigger breakpoint here
     }
     if (abserr > maxabserr) {
 //       if (isnan(abserr)) printf("abserr is Nan/n"); // testing for nan here makes results correct
        abserrloc = arg;
        maxabserr = abserr;
 //            printf("abserr %g @ %g ", abserr, arg);  // this line also makes results correct 

     }

     last_argi = argi;
//      argi++; // original code with Nan (0xffffffff)
//      argi += 0x007f0000; // the "nan" reported depends on this increment!
     argi += 0x00400000;

                        // 0x007F0000 is the largest increment that is still a Nan (0x7fc100000)
                        // 0x00400000 is Nan (0xffc00000)
                        // 0x00200000 is Nan (0xffe00000)
                        // 0x00100000 is Nan (0xfff00000) etc. 
     loopcount++;
  } while (argi>last_argi);  (false); // changing this line to prevent looping generates correct code
                          // NB it is radically different to the looping code (that fails).

  printf ("max abs err = %.6e %.6a %x @ % 15.8e %.6a\n"
          "max ulp err = %.6e @ % 15.8e\n",
          maxabserr, maxabserr, float_as_uint32(maxabserr), abserrloc, abserrloc,
          maxulperr, ulperrloc);
  printf("Nan count %i / %i\n", nancount, loopcount);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If it worked as expected then the output should be (give or take rounding errors):

```
NaN @ ffc00000
max abs err = 1.541726e-08 0x1.08ddd1p-26 32846ee9 @ -4.00000000e+00 -0x1.000000p+2
max ulp err = 1.293293e-01 @ -4.00000000e+00
```

The command line options using MS VC IDE are:

```
 /GS /W3 /Gy /Zi /O2 /Ob2 /fp:fast /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE"
 /Qipo /Zc:forScope /arch:CORE-AVX2 /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo 
 /Fo"x64\Release\" //fprofile-instr-use "x64\Release\" /Ot 
 /Fp"x64\Release\erfc_njaffa.pch"
```

Since it might be relevant the CPU is i5-12600K AlderLake Family 6 Model 7 Step 2 Ext Model 97 Rev C0 and I'm running under Win 11 Pro.

The symptom is that absmaxerr eventually ends up with a nan in it due to some weird compiler quirk when optimisation and fp:fast are used together. I can follow disassembly code execution to some extent and have tagged the max____ variables with distinctive negative denorms to make them stand out in the XMMn register set. But I haven't been able to figure out quite how it happens. I think it may be because of executing library code with nans (testing all values).

Tiny changes to the code cause radical shifts in code generated (and/or register allocation). In particular the loop branch must be taken at least once for the problem to show. Compiler generates entirely different (and working) code if while(false) is used at the end, likewise if defensive tests or a printf are put in key locations.

There are two tests for abserr is nan - one active at the outer loop level which triggers for 0x7f800000<argi<=0x7fffffff and 0xff800000<argi<=0xffffffff (IOW when argi itself is a nan). The other is commented out to put the code into a failing state and is inside the abserr>maxabserr path. If enabled there it never triggers and the code works correctly whilst the outer test continues to see nan's.

My hunch is that there is some peculiar interaction between the maximum abs value update logic and the  storing of maxabserr when argi is a nan but I just can't pin it down. abserrloc doesn't get altered after the first loop and stays at -4.0 but the initially correct maxabserr gets trampled on. Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: Is this ICX (LLVM-based), or "classic" ICC?  (I tagged ICX since 2021.10 is the last ICC version on https://godbolt.org/). When you single-step debug the asm, where does a NaN first appear in a register?

Comment: "*When compiled with [...] /fp:fast the code generated is wrong*" -- the point of various compilers' fast-math options is to allow the compiler to generate code that runs faster by making various **unsafe**, but usually correct enough, assumptions about floating-point behavior.  You should never use such flags when you depend on floating-point results being exactly correct (with respect to the implementation's fp model), or when you are pushing the system's fp boundaries.

Comment: Like John said, different rounding errors and temporaries are what you should expect with fast-math.  Also, fast-math for the whole executable usually links startup code (or for ICC perhaps calls it from `main`) that disables gradual underflow (x86 FTZ = flush to zero / DAZ = denormals are zero).  One thing that could give you a NaN is `0.0 / 0.0`, where without fast-math perhaps you're taking a ratio of two subnormals for that input.

Comment: Is the goal of this question just to understand exactly what order of operations ICC actually did, out of curiosity?  Or because you're hoping to change the source to a more efficient order of ops to get the same speedup without fast-math, if you can repair the situation to avoid NaN in that case?  Or something else?  It's unlikely to be a compiler bug; `-fp:fast` is allowed to break your FP math in certain ways if it was close to underflow, and to make code that assumes there are no infinities or NaNs.

Comment: I'd expect `if (abserr > maxabserr) {` --> `else if (abserr > maxabserr) {` to not test NANs in a `>` .

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with ICC 2021.10 and ICX 2022.2 on https://godbolt.org/z/819r7Gqd9 but Linux ICC doesn't support most of those MSVC-style options.  Classic ICC's native FP-math option is `-fp-model fast=2` for maximally-aggressive optimizations so I used that.  (I used `-xc` to compile as C, not C++).  No joy with either, both print your "expected" output, except the `NaN @ ...` printf is missing a trailing newline.  `gcc -O3 -ffast-math` counts 0 NaNs, because `-ffast-math` includes `-ffinite-math-only`; it may have optimized away the `isnan` to `false`.

Comment: @PeterCordes "it may have optimized away the `isnan` to false" is an interesting idea.

Comment: @PeterCordes ICX. Thanks for adding the tag. I didn't know there was one. The Nan gets created on the fly and somehow moved on top of the maxabserr one. I can't quite follow the logic and attempts to refine it results in the register mapping changing or the code working correctly but I don't understand why. The motivation is to have it run as quickly as possible and still work. Obvious fix to try now is never present a Nan to the routines under test.  But I'd also like to understand this problem better to avoid making a similar one in the future.

Comment: *results in the register mapping changing* - That's why I said to single-step *the asm* **with a debugger**, not to add debug-prints.  Set your debugger to disassembly mode so it shows you the actual instructions the CPU is running, and look at the XMM register results of each one that could have produced a NaN (math ops like `vdivss`, not load/store or integer ops).  I could do that if you had a version that reproduces the problem with Linux ICX (by copy/pasting the asm from Godbolt to my desktop and assembling it into an executable), or asm for a non-inline function from Windows ICX.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had already tried single stepping several times and not seen it. However, urged on by you and chux I now have a definitive cause that I think *is* a compiler bug. The working code generates  ==vmaxpd  xmm12, xmm0, xmm12== to save the maxabserr and is Nan safe but /fp:fast generates ==vmaxpd xmm12, xmm12, xmm0== sometimes instead (trashing the max value if xmm0==Nan). I saved a snapshot just after if destroyed the previously correct result right at the end. Tiny code alterations caused it to switch between the two forms (almost like it was throwing a coin to decide the order).

Comment: It probably was just treating `vmaxpd` as commutative with `-ffp-math=fast`, if it's like GCC's `-ffast-math` which lets it assume there are no NaNs so all comparisons will be ordered.  It seems to special-case `isnan` and not optimize that away (where GCC and clang do remove even that), but otherwise is assuming no NaNs because you told it that was ok.  Treating `vmaxpd` as commutative is actually useful if it allows a memory source operand, so it makes sense fast-math would do that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for that! I take your point about the memory operand but in this case it was all register to register and one way of coding it is fully compliant with no extra cost.

Comment: Right, I realize it wasn't gaining anything in *this* case.  But that's a reason why it makes sense for fast-math to disregard the possibility of comparisons being unordered.  (Probably far from the most compelling one, though.)  And it's probably not really that the compiler intentionally treats `vmaxpd` as commutative, that's probably a side-effect of ignoring the possibility of NaNs.  Anyway, does chux's answer help?  If ICX respects `isnan` when vectorizing, it could help.  Otherwise, you have code that's not suitable for fast-math because it depends on NaN handling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256660/discussion-between-martin-brown-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential problem: `>` with NAN**

C does not specify what happens with `if (abserr > maxabserr)` and a NAN is involved.  [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) does have specified functionality on such compares, yet C is not obliged to follow them.

Enabling FP performance options can reduce portability.

Suggested change to only perform relational math when the arguments are not NAN for more portable functionality:

```
 // Delay subtraction to later
 // abserr = fabs (res - ref);
 // if (isnan(abserr)) {
 if (isnan(res) || isnan(ref)) {
    nancount++;
    printf("NaN @ %8x  ", argi);
 }

 // if (abserr > maxabserr) {
 else {
    abserr = fabs (res - ref);
    if (abserr > maxabserr) {
      abserrloc = arg;
      maxabserr = abserr;
    }
 }
```

Note: some compilers (like [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) and clang) treat `isnan(x)` as false with -ffast-math because it implies -ffinite-math-only which lets them assume any `float` is non-NaN non-Inf. ICX and classic ICC don't, though, even with their respective fast-math options enabled (-ffp-model=fast and -fp-model fast=2). [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoAPrnkpJfWQE8Ayo3QBhVLQCuLBhNJOAMngMmAByngBGmMQgAOykAA6oCoT2DK4eXj4JSXYCAUGhLBFRsdaYtilCBEzEBGme3lxWmDY5DJXVBHkh4ZExVlU1dRmNCgOdgd2FvdEAlFao7sTI7BwApHoAzIHIHlgA1KsbzixMBAgAdAiH2KsaAIK3D/eBBHvMDKbICGUA1tS0qFOe1UM1W0QAQo89tC9sRMARFgw9ngFO8ICDDpD7mCACKPDhzWicACsvG8HC0pFQnGcewUCyWmAOmz0vAImgJc2%2BTCwUQgcx%2BIA2knOxI0Ug0GwAbBopQBODZcWJEjiSXgsCQaDSkcmU6kcXgKEDa9kUgmkOCwGCIFCoFhxOiRciUND2x1RZDALgbAw0WgESJGiBhDmkMKBaoAT04PDDEeIkYA8mFtGVTbHXWxBImGLRo2bSFgwu5gM4xLQjdxeFgTiZxAX8HDygA3TCVymYVRldwBmO8F7NUO0PBhYhR1xYUMEYh4DVVuZUIzABQANTwmAA7om4ow%2BzJBCIxOwpPv5Eo1KHdI0jCYQOZPoYR0bIHNUHFWpWALSJvR7T9UKgmFGT8TjOP8AHVy14VBW2IGcsGffkmhaFJHAYFw3HqHx/AmAoikyRJkgEIYGniQjWi6PDehGZo0wqMYSJ8UpygEdoakonoohGBjMOGfoOg4qYuLmelFmWfRCRJMlQ31YEAA4pU/KVJD2YBkGQPZvXOX8IFwQgSGZH0ZjZDkZgFIVolFZS9AU5SNns6IpT0aQVTVUgNXs857O8nzfKlHUZM4Q1jVIU0tDmS0bVdB16DICgIGi90UDwdS9A0PQuC4LU%2BDoANiCDEMC3DZgEz3Yqo2TVNbD3TNGAIHM81DIsSzLWgKz3GtjGAetKUbOjW3bXhO27Xsq3IQRBwLYdR3HDAVkpadZz7Bcl1Xdctx3clY34A9RHEE8drPFR1ALXQXK6u8LEfMJENfd8Ui/RMNj/Kg4hAubaD2QDRkOHFf0/SC2ug2D4LbeARNoljvAgJxGMaHD8k4gjshSOGyJR3JcKRmiUNYnj0lI5jWjY8ZEaEpj8aw7iBKx8muBEhlxL0SSOFJAKC1k1QFKUlSUo0tKMvOLLzg0PZdPwIhiEM5mTLNMzDE4NyPI2LzfLV%2Bz/N1aCgqsEKwvNSKICQBYCDiHtnQSu0YsiYJWBWLnFOU5F1L2AWuCFjQRaGiWSDwdB9FPQ99ukQ7FGOy8QGkDcxziZaFdZ6SOc4RMezN15UCoeTHd5l23Y9kWxdcN1YsMyRjNC0yWaVoUVfV9X2b1HWjRNSvSEFYVzilaJJGJYk5TlKUuD0OViU2eONkTxuDQruWLWtQ2kES2KLaX3p1JvL1onFHL/UDShCspcrSrGo%2BkxTNMartLN6tzfNeswYtS3LStY06ut5urPAmzsAbQ2G5AewrFjAOFUlJppjgTBOD%2BoUZxzh4CtJgy41ybm3LuMah0g7HhDrIMOF5TpCkMBde8lhpq3SpPdAQj1/oASAgQECpwEAQSglSEGfswYvmQnRBwMN0JowRpMfCjQshEVSLxUiwiKK00EZwqGJM0ZE3ojTMm0jRgdHkWMQSgiGZiXYMzeObMtZUk4FnHmewdhdU0pZT2XAxZ6UltLcu%2Bt5bcl5JQcyeg9DaQ8d4nx3iuByXjtXTydc1aa0CtPZuM9wpz3gEbW0xcnTxVXh6FKqgjABlGDvPKBVQynzKvGM%2BVV0y8FqtmW%2BTUH4tWfh1TAtZurQL6i2MGBZ/6AL3CAocI4IGRigVOWBcdFyILWigzae4MF7SwaeXBJ1KS6AMBvS6D5SHg3IR%2BTg35nr/leu9LAtBfrfVeADZhMFIigzIQo7hsMxHYXQpo6i6MRFowkSkO5XEZHE0pnxC5bQNFSPuaowY1zqbsT%2BcJeYOiJL6MntrDgJinapLFuktsBAZi2J9lLdYRlZbhS5JgHkvQkKuXVDXVWITvJhKThEvWpkYmwGNqnc2SSrbultmwTgDtTEIogEi0Y5dMDor9gHcZR4JDYMENMiOBho5MFjvOKFDcYUp1Nj2PYGc4U51UIi04yLUUQCLtbDFLJHGtyJe5ElZKfIKqMVSluctzIbE9nJZyko7JKmiA6ru49oXWuxZyeOrIzVZW1IY/Uvr5awSSA4SQQA)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thoughts about current fused answer?

Comment: Looks good, I applied the couple things I hadn't finished from when our edits raced.  Your current answer implies real compilers don't follow IEEE unordered compare semantics even without fast-math options ("exacerbated" means "makes worse", rather than making something happen which wasn't happening at all).  But GCC, Clang, MSVC, and ICC all do treat all of `x < y`, `x > y` and `x == y` as false when either or both are NaN, so I think that's an unnecessary amount of uncertainty.  That's why my edits have added some phrasing about mainstream compilers.

Comment: My experience with compilers does not jibe with the comments about mainstream or real compilers.  The deleted comment is not need here.  I'll review _exacerbated_.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That works fine. On balance though I think I prefer to do the calculation and then defend the assignment to maxabserr from any Nans if it gets past the initial compare since that keeps the work done in the outer loop down. See my comments to Peter above for the root cause of the problem (ordering of arguments to 'vmaxpd'). '/fp:fast' allows it the freedom to assume it is commutative (aka no Nans to worry about). Might not be at all portable if some will ignore 'isnan()' too.