MS C compiler - dramatic slowdown of AVX2 code using exp and depending on total string length
I have observed a curious phenomena with the Microsoft C compiler for a while where it seemed like the total length of strings could affect execution time of benchmarked code. This seems ridiculous but was clearly present with a ~10% effect on complex routines. I now have found a short routine that appears to show very pronounced timing variation with the length of a string in a printf statement with nothing else changing at all. The combination that causes trouble is MS VC 17.1.0 with AVX2 floating point code generation enabled and using system library exp/expf together.
Runtime is strongly dependent on the length of the printf string in mulitples of 8 and it is not subtle this is a 3-40x slowdown! I grant you that sequential benchmarks are very artificial but this sensitivity is extraordinary.
This post stems from the fast erfc thread by @njuffa . I used his test framework and had a try at producing faster and more accurate code of my own.
Originally it sat there for a couple of minutes before printing out the results. I tweaked my copy so that it would roughly fill a line with dots to indicate progress. I was struck by how very uneven the dot timing was on the float implementation so I did some more tests...
The first discovery was serendipitous and is not a fluke as I first thought. That is that the pure float implementation runs much slower. Using doubles internally for all computation avoids denorm and overflow traps for a float argument.
These are the timings for sequential incrementing of the binary representation of the floating point number (starting from 0).



Function
Intel
MS
GCC




Njuffa_f
54
273/79
41


Njuffa_d
25
440/24
25


vector
7.0
5.4
17.0


erfc
131
48/51
29


erfcf
27
97/92
18



And these are the more realistic timings for long period random numbers using randq1 (so as to make branch prediction almost useless).



Function
Intel
MS
GCC




Njuffa_f
85
285/88
99


Njuffa_d
59
309/41
97


vector
33.2
27.0
43.6


erfc
135
63/68
60


erfcf
27
97/92
109/107



Microsoft timings show the slow/fast times where appropriate.
I still don't feel I am getting the optimum performance out of GCC - compiler options were:
gcc -O3 -Ofast -mavx2 -march=native erfc_njuffa.cpp -lm

Any suggestions for additional compiler flags to speed it up a bit?
This was meant to be an MRE for showing off the difference in performance between a pure float scalar function and one which uses double precision computation internally. Roughly speaking the double precision implementation is about 2x faster but loses some (or on GCC most) of its advantage when challenged with more realistic random data.
However, when I simplified it down to just the bare bones timing loop rather than a full functional test (system erfc double precision rounded to float is very slow and hides timing variations) I found it behaved very strangely on the Microsoft compiler v17.1.0 whereas on GCC and Intel the timings are similar in all cases and also for SSE2, AVX, AVX2 code gen.
On MS C the benchmarks slow down by a factor of 40x for double and 4x for float when the string table length is unfavourable. I do not have an explanation for this behaviour. My best guess is some sort of MMX data or L1 cache misalignment pipeline stall.
The big question here is have I succeeded to make an MRE for this errant behaviour?
This is the putative MRE code. Add a few characters to the printf string to slow it down (or 32 characters to speed up again).  I used "0123456789ABCDEFGH...V" for 32 character padding.:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

/* Default is a sweep of floats upwards from binary representation of 0 in steps of 1
   RANDOM uses a 2^32 period RNG randq1 to break branch prediction patterns (more realistic usage)
   CRUDE replaces system library exp, expf with a pathetic fast approximation
   avoiding use of system math library exp on MS compiler avoids slowdown problem
 */

 //#define RANDOM     (1)
 //#define CRUDE (1)

#ifdef CRUDE
#define exp(x) (2+x)/(2-x)
#define expf(x) (2+x)/(2-x)
#endif 

float uint32_as_float(uint32_t a)
{
  float r;
  memcpy(&r, &a, sizeof r);
  return r;
}

/* Fast computation of the complementary error function. For argument x > 0
   erfc(x) = exp(-x*x) * P(x) / Q(x), where P(x) and Q(x) are polynomials.
   If expf() is faithfully rounded, the following error bounds should hold:
   Maximum relative error < 1.065e-5, maximum absolute error < 9.50e-6, and
   maximum ulp error < 176.5 see this post for details
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741402/fast-implementation-of-complementary-error-function-with-5-digit-accuracy
*/

float njf_fast_erfcf(float x)
{   // pure float implementation

  float c, e, p, q, r, s;
  c = fabsf(x);
  if (c > 10.5f) c = 10.5;  // original NJuffa code
  s = -c * c;
  e = expf(s);
  q = 3.82346243e-1f;  //  0x1.8785c6p-2
  p = -4.38094139e-5f;  // -0x1.6f8000p-15
  q = fmaf(q, c, 1.30382288e+0f); //  0x1.4dc756p+0
  p = fmaf(p, c, 2.16852024e-1f); //  0x1.bc1ceap-3
  q = fmaf(q, c, 1.85278833e+0f); //  0x1.da5056p+0
  p = fmaf(p, c, 7.23953605e-1f); //  0x1.72aa0cp-1
  q = fmaf(q, c, 9.99991655e-1f); //  0x1.fffee8p-1
  p = fmaf(p, c, 1.00000000e+0f); //  0x1.000000p+0
  r = e / q;
  r = r * p;
  if (x < 0.0f) r = 2.0f - r;
  if (isnan(x)) r = x + x;
  return r;
}

float njd_fast_erfcf(float x)
{   // pure double implementation

  double c, e, p, q, r, s;
  c = fabs(x);
  if (c > 10.5f) c = 10.5;  // original NJuffa code
  s = -c * c;
  e = exp(s);
  q = 3.82346243e-1;  //  0x1.8785c6p-2
  p = -4.38094139e-5;  // -0x1.6f8000p-15
  q = fma(q, c, 1.30382288e+0); //  0x1.4dc756p+0
  p = fma(p, c, 2.16852024e-1); //  0x1.bc1ceap-3
  q = fma(q, c, 1.85278833e+0); //  0x1.da5056p+0
  p = fma(p, c, 7.23953605e-1); //  0x1.72aa0cp-1
  q = fma(q, c, 9.99991655e-1); //  0x1.fffee8p-1
  p = fma(p, c, 1.00000000e+0); //  0x1.000000p+0
  r = e / q;
  r = r * p;
  if (x < 0.0f) r = 2.0 - r;
  if (isnan(x)) r = x + x;
  return (float) r;
}

float faster_erfcf(float x)
{   // vector float implementation hybrid erfc and exp 

  float c, e, r, s, f, j, ue;
  int i;
  const float B = 1.12797f; // optimised
  __m128 p3, p2, p1, p0, xv, zv;

  //                           p_n                 q_n                                  plo_exp                   phi_exp
  const float p3vec[4] = { -4.38094139e-5f, 3.82346243e-1f,   1.66664720e-1f * 0x1p-24f, 0.0 };
  const float p2vec[4] = { 2.16852024e-1f, 1.30382288e+0f,   4.99999851e-1f * 0x1p-24f, 1.37805939e-3f * 0x1p-24f };
  const float p1vec[4] = { 7.23953605e-1f, 1.85278833e+0f,   1.0f * 0x1p-24f,           8.37312452e-3f * 0x1p-24f };
  const float p0vec[4] = { 1.0f,           9.99991655e-1f,   1.0f * 0x1p-24f,           4.16695364e-2f * 0x1p-24f };

float res[4];
//    if (isnan(x)) return x + x; // adding this slows it down !
c = fabsf(x);
if (c > 10.2)  // was 10.5
{
    if (x < 0) return 2.0f; else return 0.0f;
} // was r = 0.0;  // special case here = faster exit
else
{
      if (c < 0.038f) return 1.0f - B * x; // equal ripple error near zero = faster exit & more accurate
      s = -c * c;
      // Njuffa's exp(x) inlined and rescaled for speed
      // exp(s) = 2**i * exp(f); i = rintf (s / log(2))
      j = fmaf(1.442695f, s, 12582912.f); // 0x1.715476p0 // log2(e)
      j = j - 12582912.f; // 0x1.8p23  // 2**23+2**22
      f = fmaf(j, -6.93145752e-1f, s); // -0x1.62e400p-1  // log_2_hi 
      f = fmaf(j, -1.42860677e-6f, f); // -0x1.7f7d1cp-20 // log_2_lo 
      i = (int)j + 24;                 
      // approximate r = exp(f) on interval [-log(2)/2, +log(2)/2]

      res[0] = res[1] = c; res[2] = res[3] = f;
      xv = _mm_load_ps(res);
      p3 = _mm_load_ps(p3vec);
      p2 = _mm_load_ps(p2vec);
      zv = _mm_fmadd_ps(xv, p3, p2);
      p1 = _mm_load_ps(p1vec);
      p0 = _mm_load_ps(p0vec);
      zv = _mm_fmadd_ps(zv, xv, p1);
      zv = _mm_fmadd_ps(zv, xv, p0);
      _mm_store_ps(res, zv);
      ue = uint32_as_float((i << 23) - 0xC0800000);  // was - 0x81000000 - 0x3f800000); / 
 // optimised for range used
      f = f * f;
      e = res[2] + f * f * res[3];
      e = e * ue;
      r = e / res[1];
      r = r * res[0];
  }
  if (x < 0.0f) r = 2.0f - r;
  //    if (isnan(x)) r = x + x;
  return r;
}

void timefun(const char* name, float (*test_fun)(float), bool verbose)
{
  uint32_t argi, largi=0;
  float arg, res, sum;
  time_t start, end;
  printf("\nTiming %s\n", name);
  argi = 0;
  sum = 0.0;
  start = clock();
  do {
      arg = uint32_as_float(argi);
      res = (*test_fun)(arg);
      if ((argi & 0x7f800000)!= 0x7f800000) // defend isnan against GCC -Ofast optimiser
        if (!isnan(res)) sum += res;
#ifdef RANDOM
      argi = (argi * 1664525 + 1013904223); // ranqd1 
#else
      argi++; // sequential
#endif
      if (verbose && ((argi & 0xff800000) != largi))  // verbose = display time per exponent value
      {
          end = clock();
          largi = argi & 0xff800000;
          printf("Exp %x : %6.3f\n", argi >> 20, (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
          start = clock();
      }
      if ((argi & 0x3ffffff) == 0) printf(".");
  } while (argi);
  end = clock();
  printf("\ntime taken %6.2f  sum = %g\n", (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, sum);
}

int main(void)
{                                       //0123456789ABCDEF0  
  printf("printf string 01234567\n"); // add one extra character to printf string here to radically alter timing behaviour on MSC v17.1.0

  timefun("Njuffad", njd_fast_erfcf, false);  
  timefun("Njuffaf", njf_fast_erfcf, false);  
#ifndef RANDOM
  timefun("Njuffaf", njf_fast_erfcf, true);   
#endif
  timefun("Vectorf", faster_erfcf, false);        // handcoded vector reference
  timefun("erfcf",  erfcf, false);                // system erfcf for reference
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

If it is working at full speed it prints a few dots per second and if it is misbehaving the first dot takes about 5s to appear!
Can anyone else using Microsoft C/C++ compilers reproduce the timing variation that I see below when truncating the string in the printf statement at various positions. Padding to nearest multiple of 8 bytes with nulls means that the data layout alters every 8 bytes added. However, there are hints that the previous compile and/or other factors unknown are also relevant to the behaviour. CPU turbo clock variations can account for +/-15%. All times are in seconds of wall clock time.



Last Char
double NJ erfc
float NJ erfc




0-7
22
78


8-F
430
270


G-N
430
270


O-V
430
78


0-7'
22
78


8-F'
428
270


G-N'
427
78


O-V'
22
78


0-7"
430
270



In all cases the full vector treatment took 5.4s +/-0.05 and the system erfc 95s +/-0.5s which provides a fast and a slow reference to correct for CPU clock shifts.
The other detailed verbose analysis of the timings of NJ_erfcf float implementation show the algorithm's intrinsic slow points that first got me interested in speeding things up.



Hex code
exponent
Time/s
Notes




000
-128
0.8
positive edge case inifinity & Nans


008
-127
1.5
positive denormals (v slow)


010-180
-126
0.04
x^2 flush to zero


188-200
-79
0.35
x^2 is a denormal


208-410
-61
0.04
x^2 is normal number


418
3
0.13
conditional branch > 10.5


420-7f8
4
0.016
fastest path


800
-128
0.76
negative edge case infinity & Nans


808
-127
1.5
negative denormals (v slow)



When it is misbehaving then everything is about 3-40x slower. Most exponents taking about 1s to process which is an enormous slow down that I cannot explain.
The symptoms are that performance depends critically on the length of the string table and can be altered by changing the length of the string constant in the printf statement at the start of main. String table is padded with nulls up to the next 8 byte boundary by default. I suspect the MSVC IDE run environment may be partly to blame since timings do seem to be more consistent from inside an independent DOS shell. The slow ones still run slow though - just not quite as slow. To get consistent timings it is necessary not to touch mouse or keyboard after starting it running.
I thought that the pattern repeated exactly every 32 bytes but it seems on closer inspection that some variation is possible. A given compiled executable has repeatable timeings to within measurement noise.
If any one can reproduce this symptom (only present on the Microsoft 2022 compiler or any other earlier release) I would be very interested. I have my suspicions that it is something odd about my hardware Win11 i5-12600K Alder Lake and/or how my environment is set up. This is the closest I have ever got to an MRE for it. Here adding a single character to the string "01234567\n" will tip it over the edge into glacial slowness. Even if you can't reproduce it I'd still like suggestions for what else to try and pin it down.
Njuffa's code seems to be exquisitely sensitive to whatever the thing is that changes the runtime of what is essentially identical binary executable with its data shifted along by multiples of 8 bytes. The only thing that visibly changes in the disassembly is the addresses of the various constants in the data segment - code branches and destinations remain fixed.
My system is Win 11 x64 Pro CPU i5-12600 and the
MSC 17.1.0 compiler options are:
  /GS- /Qpar /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /sdl /Zc:inline /fp:fast 
  /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:AVX2 
  /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot 

I think that the MSC system library functions exp/expf may be implicated in the slow down since if I substitute a really crude approximation of my own (answers are wrong) or a better one by Njaffa the slowdown vanishes completely.

I tried running the code but I'm getting bored already, can you make this take like a minute or two instead of a half hour

@harold thanks for taking a look. If you want to speed it up 16x swap the line "argi++; // sequential" for "argi += 16" (other powers of 2 are available). What CPU are you running it on?  The difference should be obvious in the first few seconds if it is going at a sensible speed or not. Dots per second vs seconds per dot. It is possible that on another system the dead slow mode might be for some other string length. BTW Code is untested on AMD - I don't have any to hand.

OK, I tried various lengths, and didn't see any strange perf fluctuation like that (but a "full" run of njd_fast_erfcf takes around 110 seconds, surely Alder Lake is not 5x as fast as Rocket Lake? what's up with that). I'm running it on a 11600K aka Rocket Lake, also compiling with VS 2022.

Ignore the part about 110 seconds that was an error on my part, but still I don't see those wild perf fluctuations

@harold 'njd_fast_erfcftakes ~80 here take 77s so at 110s you are about 50% slower. If you enter the wading through treacle mode it will be 4-40x slower. What version of VSC are you using? I'm aware that my copy is a bit behind the times now. What time do you get for the double and vectorised faster version (which I am now fairly confident runs almost as fast as is possible on AVX architecture - but improvements are still most welcome). I also know from tracing the code that the MSexp/expf` code is rather cache unfriendly (I'll start a new thread about that soon).
